# Visual Studio Code Integrated Terminal not Displaying Text

Tags: c++, terminal, visual-studio-code

I'm brand new to MacOS and I am attempting to set up a programming environment, my IDE of choice being Visual Studio Code. When the program runs it, by default, prints in output. However, output crashes when asked to gather input. The online solution the I found for that was to output the code through the terminal, yet now nothing is displayed in the terminal.

I'm posting this here instead of a bug report as I'm unsure whether the fault is mine or the program's.

Here is the simple code I am attempting to run:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i;
    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> i;
    std::cout << "\n" << i;
    return 0; 
}
```

When run through output, it will display the first part, then crash when input is requested. When run through the terminal, the terminal only displays: "cd "(directory location)" && g++ main.cpp -o main && "(directory location)"main" and nothing else.

Below are my tasks.json and launch.json:

tasks.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "c++ test program",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "g++",
            "args": [
                "-g", "main.cpp"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

launch.json:

```
{
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "(lldb) Launch",
                "type": "cppdbg",
                "request": "launch",
                "program": "${workspaceRoot}/a.out",
                "args": [],
                "stopAtEntry": false,
                "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "environment": [],
                "externalConsole": true,
                "MIMode": "lldb"
            }
        ]
    }
```

The only setting that has been changed would be "code-runner.runInTerminal" which has been set to true.

Comment: Are you running in teh terminal the `./a.out` command? Since what you show it command for compiling the program - not running it. Compile the code in the VSCode. Open terminal (build in or external) and run `ls` - see that a.out is generated. Run `./a.out`

Comment: Using either terminal nothing occurs when typing either command, or both together. It appears that the code compiles but does not run.

Comment: voting to close as "not reproducible". see the asker's comment under wasmup's answer post.

Comment: as for why this question has 5 upvotes, I imagine it might have to do with the current limitation of the C/C++ extension with consoles on macOS, and that- unlike on other platforms- if `externalConsole` is `false` (which it is by default), output will go to the debug console instead of an integrated terminal ([docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference#_externalconsole)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true when using [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)
so the solution is:
use [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) and then press `Ctrl+,` to edit settings then search for
`code-runner.runInTerminal` and set `code-runner.runInTerminal` to `true`, like so:

```
{
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true
}
```

this works fine for me.
I hope this helps.

Comment: I've already done this prior to asking the question. The code runs until an input is requested if set to false. If set to true the code doesn't run at all.

Comment: try to Change VSCode Integrated Terminal, may be [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) helps: [Mac OS X: Change shell for integrated terminal](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22161).

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I messed up my path doing something else and by extension my terminal. I was able to fix it by removing .bash_profile. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @HarpoN did this answer post actually help you at all? why did you mark it as accepted?